# How can I group and get MS Access query to show only rows with a maximum value in a specified field for a consecutive number of times?

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, count

I have a large access table that I need to pull specific data from with a query.

I need to get a list of all the IDs that meet a specific criteria, i.e. 3 months in a row with a cage number less than 50.

The SQL code I'm currently working with is below, but it only gives me which months of the past 3 had a cage number below 50.

```
SELECT [AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database].AnimalID, [AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database].Date, [AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database].Cage
FROM [AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database]
WHERE ((([AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database].Date)>=DateAdd("m",-3,Date())) AND (([AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database].Cage)<50))
ORDER BY [AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database].AnimalID DESC;
```

I would need it to look at the past 3 months for each ID, and only output if all 3 met the specific criteria, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Data Sample:

| Date | AnimalID | Cage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6/28/2022 | 12345 | 50 |
| 5/19/2021 | 12345 | 32 |
| 3/20/2008 | 12345 | 75 |
| 5/20/2022 | 23569 | 4 |
| 8/20/2022 | 23569 | 4 |
| 5/20/2022 | 44444 | 71 |
| 8/1/2012 | 44444 | 4 |
| 4/1/2022 | 78986 | 30 |
| 1/20/2022 | 78986 | 1 |
| 9/14/2022 | 65659 | 59 |
| 8/10/2022 | 65659 | 48 |
| 7/14/2022 | 65659 | 30 |
| 6/14/2022 | 95659 | 12 |
| 8/14/2022 | 91111 | 51 |
| 7/14/2022 | 91111 | 5 |
| 6/14/2022 | 91111 | 90 |
| 8/14/2022 | 88888 | 4 |
| 7/14/2022 | 88888 | 5 |
| 6/14/2022 | 88888 | 15 |

Comment: You could do `where exists (select 1 FROM [AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database] as adb2 where adb2.Date>=DateAdd("m",-3,Date()) and adb2.cage<50 and adb2.AnimalID=adb.AnimalID)  and exists (select 1 FROM [AbBehWeeklyMonitor Database] as adb2 where adb2.Date>=DateAdd("m",-2,Date()) and adb2.cage<50 and)` and so on.  You'll need to alias the table in your main query,`adb` would be how i've shown.  Unsure if this is the best method, or you can extend your original `where` or perhaps a count of 3 for the criteria, if you can ensure that there is one entry per month perhaps? can you show some sample data.

Comment: Data should be provided as text table, not image. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables.

Comment: @June7 I added the data table like you recommended, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @HansUp I would want it to output rows 11-13 and 17-19 (because They were all in the past 3 months and had a cage number below 50), but not rows 14-16 because not all cage numbers in the past 3 months were below 50.

Comment: If you want to reference records by a row number, why not include that in the table? Is there a unique identifier field - an autonumber ID? Is that a typo for the AnimalID on row 13?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

Query1:

```
SELECT AnimalID, Count(*) AS Cnt
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Cage)<50) AND (([Date]) Between #6/1/2022# And #8/31/2022#))
GROUP BY AnimalID
HAVING (((Count(*))=3));
```

Query2

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM Query1 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Query1.AnimalID = Table1.AnimalID
WHERE ((([Date]) Between #6/1/2022# And #8/31/2022#));
```

Output:

```
Date      AnimalID  Cage
6/14/2022   65659   12
7/14/2022   65659   30
8/10/2022   65659   48
6/14/2022   88888   15
7/14/2022   88888   5
8/14/2022   88888   4
```

Date is a reserved word and really should not use reserved words as names.